# Отправка POST из value="значение" после нажатия на submit

Tags: input, post, html

Всем привет.

```
<div class="method">
                <form class="form_test_form" action="/api/template" method="post">
                    <input class="form_field form_param_path form_param_required form_param_submit"
                           name="overlay"
                           type="text" value="" size="3"/>
                    <input style="width: 62px" type="submit" value="overlay"/></form>
            </div>
```

Значение, что вводится в `<input>`, должно отправляться после нажатия на кнопку `submit`.

Таких div´a 2шт, при нажатии на кнопку submit отправляются оба сразу. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, к чему такие сложности и зачем всё заворачивать в each?

```
    $('.form_test_form').on('submit', function () {
        var $form = $(this);
        var submitParams = $form.serialize();
        var url = $form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                processData: true,
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                data: submitParams,
                headers: ({"Auth-Secret": $("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
                success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Тоже не помогло, перекидывает на новую страницу и не отправляет.

Answer (score 1):

В этой форме 1 поле text, при нажатии submit отправится только оно. Проверьте, закрыты ли обе формы (`</form>`) и нет ли обработки JS нажатия на submit.

Comment: Обе формы закрыты.  
Вот, собственно, мой js:  

http://pastebin.com/N8uMCAHs